# Returning specific regions

Tags: matlab, return, label, region

Say that I have a labeled image, where I have calculated the `area` of each region. How can I return specific regions? That is, say I want to return the regions that have `>=300` and `<500`?

Thanks.

Comment: are you going to ask a question about every single line of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the results of `regionprops` into a vector and use it for indexing:

```
rg = regionprops( L, 'Area' );
allArea = [rg(:).Area]; % grouping all area values into a single vecotr
labels = find( allArea >= 300 & allArea < 500); % select relevant regions
```